# what is the expected performance of ZeroMQ?

Tags: javascript, performance, coffeescript, message-queue, zeromq

I am dabbling with process-to-process communication; the aim is to have worker processes that perform some computations and pass back the result to a controlling process. I installed [zeromq.node](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node) and set up a simple requester and responder in coffeescript.

the requester:

```
# requester.coffee

zmq                       = require 'zmq'
context                   = new zmq.Context()
socket                    = zmq.socket 'req'

socket.bind 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5555', ( error ) =>
  throw error if error?
  console.log 'Requesting writer bound to port 5555'
  setInterval ( -> socket.send 'helo world' ), 1


response_count  = 0
t0              = new Date() / 1000

socket.on 'message', ( message ) ->
  response_count += 1
  # x = message.toString 'utf-8'
  if response_count % 1000 is 0
    t1              = new Date() / 1000
    console.log "received #{ parseInt response_count / ( t1 - t0 ) + 0.5 } messages per second"
    response_count  = 0
    t0 = new Date() / 1000
```

The responder:

```
# responder.coffee

zmq                       = require 'zmq'
context                   = new zmq.Context()
socket                    = zmq.socket 'rep'

socket.connect 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'
console.log 'Responder bound to port 5555'
process.stdin.resume()

request_count   = 0
t0              = new Date() / 1000

socket.on 'message', ( message ) ->
  request_count += 1
  # message = message.toString 'utf-8'
  # console.log message
  socket.send 'helo back'
  if request_count % 1000 is 0
    t1              = new Date() / 1000
    console.log "received #{ parseInt request_count / ( t1 - t0 ) + 0.5 } messages per second"
    request_count  = 0
    t0 = new Date() / 1000
```

Now when I run them in separate terminal windows on my ubuntu (11.10, 8GB, Intel Duo Core 3GHz, NodeJS 0.8.6) machine, I get the following output:

```
received 135 messages per second
received 6369 messages per second
received 6849 messages per second
received 6944 messages per second
received 7042 messages per second
received 7143 messages per second
received 5952 messages per second
received 2967 messages per second
received 914 messages per second
received 912 messages per second
received 928 messages per second
received 919 messages per second
received 947 messages per second
received 906 messages per second
received 918 messages per second
received 929 messages per second
received 916 messages per second
received 917 messages per second
received 916 messages per second
received 928 messages per second
```

which (1) looks a little like there is some kind of saturation in the transmission channel after a few seconds; (2) feels not fast enough. according to [this benchmark](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.de/2011/04/message-queue-shootout.html), I should be in the hundreds of thousands – not thousands – of messages per seconds, which is corrobrated by [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921324/performance-comparison-between-zeromq-rabbitmq-and-apache-qpid) ("ZeroMQ: It takes about 15 milli seconds to receive 10,000 messages").

I have also tried to to use a responder written in python 3 and got the exact same numbers. what's more, I wrote an alternative pair of scripts, where the master process would spawn a child process and communicate with it over stdout/stdin; I obtained around 750 messages per second (I couldn't see much variance when I increased message length), which is in like the same ballpark as the zeromq experiment.

Are these numbers to be expected? What is the limiting factor here?

Comment: Synchronous REQ-REP is the main limit, see the guide for more asynchronous examples to raise the performance rate.

Comment: not sure i understand you correctly, but no matter how many responder terminals i open, the requester's  reported rate always stays in the 900 mps range. now the requester is certainly not blocking, and it sends out requests as fast as it can – as for javascript on nodejs, certainly faster than 1 request per millisecond?

Comment: you have `setInterval...1`, doesn't that mean it's only sending one message every millisecond?  That would give you an upper limit of 1k msgs/sec. Remove the setInterval, and put socket.send inside the `on 'message'` block for the requester if you really want to see its limit.

Comment: Steve-o is right, REQ-REP is synchronous and will always be much slower because it has to wait for a response. The kind of performance you are looking for you can accomplish with PUSH-PULL.

Comment: @flow Looks like commenters have moved on; could you post the push/pull version of your code as the answer? (since this does appear to be answered)

Answer (score 7):

I think two things are going on. First, you have `setInterval ( -> socket.send 'helo world' ), 1`. This sends a request every millisecond, so you are going to be limited to 1000 request per second.

Also, the request/response model is synchronous. A request comes in on a socket and blocks until a response is given. With the response, the next request is processed and blocked.

I changed the requester script from `socket = zmq.socket 'req'` to `socket = zmq.socket 'push'` and `setInterval ( -> socket.send 'helo world' ), 0` to `socket.send 'helo world' while true`. I then changed the responder script `socket = zmq.socket 'rep'` to `socket = zmq.socket 'pull'` and got this output

```
$ coffee responder.coffee
Responder bound to port 5555
received 282 messages per second
received 333357 messages per second
received 249988 messages per second
received 333331 messages per second
received 250003 messages per second
received 333331 messages per second
received 333331 messages per second
received 333331 messages per second
...
```

The requester got no output because it was blocking on the while loop, but it does demonstrate that ØMQ can get much better performance.